# Panel in the middle of page with 2 column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a problem to make this panel compatible with all resolution (mobile and desktop). How can I with CSS solve this problem? For example move in a second line the table keeping centered de box (with display flex property) when there isn't enough space. Also the height of image must be as six row of my table.

HTML:

```
<section id="sq-container">
    <div class="vert-mid">
        <h1 class="titleSection">Title</h1>
        <div id="boxSq" style="display: block;" class="menu w3-card w3-white w3-container">
            <a href="url"><img class="w3-half" src="url"></a>
            <div class="w3-half" style="padding-right: 0;">
                <table>
                    <tbody>( my table data, max 6 rows and 3 columns )</tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul id="choosectrl">
            <li>
                <a onclick="javascript:back();" class="icon fa-arrow-left"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a onclick="javascript:home();" class="icon fa-home"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
section {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
.vert-mid {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#boxSq {
    padding: 12px;
    width: 60%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#boxSq table {
    width: 96%;
    float: right;
    text-align: left;
    border: 0 none;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
#boxSq tr:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}
#boxSq td {
    padding: 7.7px 10px;
}
```

This is my idea:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5voPN.jpg

This is the result that work with only big resolution:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4hDf.jpg

any suggestion?

Sorry for my bad english :)

Answer (score 0):

It is easiest to collapse the parent container so the side-by-side divs become stacked in mobile. I used flex on the parent after a certain screen size that will cause them to move into a single row.

Edit: media queries don't work as well in the stack overflow code editor but if you "expand snippet" and adjust your screen size to below 500px you will see the change.

```css
.section{
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
}

.block{
  padding:2em;
}

.block:first-child{ background-color:red; }
.block:last-child{ background-color:blue; }

@media(min-width:500px){
  .block-container{
    display:flex;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="section">

  <div class="block-container">
    <div class="block">
    <p>This is left</p>
    </div><!-- block -->
    <div class="block">
    <p>This is right</p>
    </div><!-- block -->
  </div><!-- block-container -->
  
</div><!-- section -->
```